# How to pass variables as parameters to Bigquery command line in shell script

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute Bigquery command line through my shell script.
For eg :

```
#!/bin/bash
bq mk -t 'projectid':'datasetid'.'TEMP_table1'
```

Above script works fine.
But my requirement is to pass table name randomly that I need to create. so, I execute below commands in my shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash
Tablename=$1

echo $Tablename
bq mk -t 'projectid':'datasetid'."$(Tablename)"
```

When I run it as `./test.sh 'Temp_table'` command fails with error :

> ./test.sh: line 13: Tablename: command not found
>   BigQuery error in mk operation: Cannot determine table described by financelcr:datasetid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do by `$(..)` is command-substitution to run commands within a sub-shell. What you need is variable expansion of syntax `${..}`. Change your command use the argument directly

```
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { printf "Arguments not supplied\n"; exit 1; }
bq mk -t 'projectid':'datasetid'."${1}"
```